# How to set div background to new bgcolor using javascript by not show old bgcolor before?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to set div background to new `bgcolor` using `javascript` by not show old bgcolor before ?

Have to tested on slowly speed, When test code i'll see old `bgcolor`(black) before new `bgcolor`(red). How to show new `bgcolor`(red) only by not to show old `bgcolor`(black) ?

https://jsfiddle.net/cj1do7pv/1/

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("xx").style.backgroundColor  = "red";
</script>
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? I can't understand it.

Comment: So why not just set the div bgcolor to red initially?!

Comment: your div has inline css or external?

Comment: Lots of questions, Why not set initial CSS style, Do you want Vanilla JS or Jquery? Your fiddle links jquery; however, you are using Vanilla Js. What do you mean tested on slowly speed?

Comment: @magreenberg, I assume recording the screen, and decreasing the frames per second--a thought!

Comment: your fiddle never shows background anything but red - so doesn't demonstrate the issue very well. if you have inline css background colour, then I'm afraid the browser will honour that style, because browsers don't "know" that you don't really want it black, but want to at some time change it to red ... you'll have to wait many years before browsers are smart enough to "know what you mean" rather than "do what you told it to do"

Comment: @JaromandaX I feel for the browser, I don't understand what he means either.

Comment: Do you need to set a random background color each time which is unique?

Comment: @magreenberg - I know exactly what he means, and have basically told him that there's very little he can do except to make sure the javascript that changes the background colour runs before the element is rendered, but after the element is "defined" - something which I think is unpossible, or not conrollable

Comment: Somebody pls edit the question to make it understandeable

Comment: can't understand exactly what you want.please explain it well

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript works fine but heres a quick code that i would write:

HTML

```
<div id="xx"></div>
```

CSS

```
#xx{
 width:500px;
 height:500px;
background-color:black;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#xx").css({"background-color":"red"});
});
```

You can use jquery if you like but if you dont want to you can use javascript that you had given in the question

Javascript(if you use this dont use the jquery code)

```
document.getElementById("xx").style.backgroundColor="red";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
 { 
  $("#xx").css("background-color","red");
  });
```